# Racket - Writing a predicate

Tags: racket, predicate

So I'm slightly confused on an introduction to Racket.

I need to write a function called "extend" that takes an element and a predicate, and "extends" the predicate to include the element. For example:

```
    ((extend 1 even?) 1)
    #t
    ((extend 3 even?) 3)
    #f
```

I'm fairly new to the language but I don't understand how to get a function to be used or return as a predicate. Not sure if I'm overthinking it or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is just a value and `extend` is just a variable like `+` and `cons` that evaluate to a function value. functions can be passed as arguments and you just use whatever name you have given it as if it's a function, by using parentheses, and it just works.

A function returns the value the last expression evaluate to. To get it to be a function it either needs to be a variable that evaluate to a function or a lambda that also evaluate to a function.

```scm
(define (double-up fn)
  (lambda (value)
    (fn (fn value)))) ; see. Just use fn as if it is a procedure

((double-up add1) 4) ; ==> 6
(define add2 (double-up add1))
(add2 4) ; ==> 6

(define error-use (double-up 5)) ; works like a charm
(error-use 4) 
; Signals "application: not a procedure" 
; since `5` isn't a procedure.
```

Here is another example which is more similar to your assignment. It takes a number, then returns a function that takes another number and then adds them together. Here I choose to define it locally and then leave it as the last expession so that it becomes the result.

```scm
(define (make-add initial-value)
  (define (adder new-value)
    (+ initial-value new-value))

  adder) ; this is the result

((make-add 5) 7) ; ==> 12
```

A predicate is what we call functions often called in predicate position in conditionals (like `if` and `cond`). Thus just a function that either return `#t` or `#f` and often bound to variables ending with question mark as a naming convention.